# Compare input with data in txt files using C

Tags: c, struct

so I am trying to use struct and txt files to build a login form, I use a function for registration that saves username and password to txt file and another function for the login part by reading and comparing values from what the user input.

However the code seems to compare only the first line of username and password! The rest only gives wrong credentials, how do I make it compare the rest?

Struct

```
struct user
{
    char userID[10];
    char username[50];
    char password[50];
};
```

Register Function

```
char registration()
{

    system("cls");
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\tWelcome to Registration Page\n");
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    date();

    struct user person;

    printf("Enter the UserID: ");
    scanf(" %s", person.userID);

    printf("\nEnter the username: ");
    scanf(" %s", person.username);

    printf("\nEnter the password: ");
    scanf(" %s", person.password);

    printf("This person has username %s and password %s\n", person.username, person.password);


    FILE *outfile;

    // open file for writing
    outfile = fopen ("user.txt", "a");
    if (outfile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n");
        exit (1);
    }


    // write struct to file
    fwrite (&person, sizeof(struct user), 1, outfile);
    fclose(outfile);

    if(fwrite != 0)
        printf("\ncontents to file written successfully !\n");
    else
        printf("error writing file !\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Login function:

```
int login()
{
    //system("cls");
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\tWelcome to Login Page\n");
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    date();

    char username[50];
    char password[50];

    FILE *infile;
    struct user person;


    printf("\nPlease Enter your Username, Password to Proceed\n\n");
    printf("\n\nUsername: ");
    scanf(" %s", &username);
    printf("\nPassword: ");
    scanf(" %s", &password);

    infile = fopen ("user.txt", "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    // read file contents till end of file

    while(fread(&person, sizeof(struct user), 1, infile)){
        if(strcmp(username,person.username) == 0 && \
           strcmp(password, person.password) ==0)
        {
            hrmenu();
            break;
        }    
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong Credentials, Please try again!\n");
            login();    
        }
    }

    fclose(infile);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Why do you open `infile` twice in `login()`? (BTW, use `perror` for error reporting, it knows _why_ the file was not opened.)

Comment: Note that adding a space before the `"%s"` has no effect.

Comment: Storing passwords in plain text is fundamentally insecure. While this might just be a programming exercise it's a bad habit to get into. ["Secure Salted Password Hashing"](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) is a good place to start reading up on storing passwords.

Comment: @DYZ My bad, edited

Comment: @Schwern No, just some assignment with text requirements, but thanks for the info

Comment: Your input is too long.  Post text entered.

Comment: @chux 1st set of data used username = Test password = Test (Works Fine)
2nd set username = A Password = A (Does not work)
3rd set username = John Password = Doe (Does not work)

If i delete the file and replace 1st set with A and A it will login with A and A but not the other options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that hrmenu() is the call that is actually logging you in, so lets take a look at your while loop.

```
while(fread(&person, sizeof(struct user), 1, infile))
{
    ...
}
```

The while portion looks good, it looks like you're going to keep reading until fread returns something non-zero.  Okay.  How about the if statement, then:

```
if(strcmp(username,person.username) == 0 && \
       strcmp(password, person.password) ==0)
    {
        hrmenu();
        break;
    }    
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong Credentials, Please try again!\n");
        login();    
    }
```

So on the first time that this is executed, if the user name and password are correct, we execute hrmenu().  If one or both are incorrect, we print "wrong credentials" and go back to the login().

I think what you mean to do here is put the else statement outside of the while.  Like this:

```
bool logged_in = false;
while(fread(&person, sizeof(struct user), 1, infile)){
    if(strcmp(username,person.username) == 0 && \
       strcmp(password, person.password) ==0)
    {
        hrmenu();
        logged_in = true;
        break;
    }    
}

fclose(infile);  

if(!logged_in)
{  
    printf("Wrong Credentials, Please try again!\n");
    login();
}    
return 0;
```